# Elixir , how can i run a CMD command that needs admin privileges?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm in the windows environment and I need my program to be able to run a CMD command as an administrator...

when I try to run via System.cmd the exception return is

message: `Unable to remove service (not enough privileges?)`

Edit:

Using iex -S mix the program works normally
but when I generate the release and work erlsrv
https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlsrv.html

it is installed as a service on windows but a service without permissions to run on CMD

Comment: What happens when you run Elixir as Admin?

Comment: on Windows OS I get that message to perform tasks that require admin rules

Comment: In Windows right click on the program icon for Elixir. Then from the pop-up context menu select Run As Administrator.  Windows will put up a modal window asking "Do you want to run this App" - giving the name as werl.exe.  That is the Erlang interpreter upon which Elixir runs.  Click Yes.  Then you ought to have sufficient permissions from Windows to do what you need in Elixir.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is solved by giving your user a permission to run the program under your user with `sudo` without a password.

In `/etc/sudoers`:

```bash
your_user        ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service_to_run
```

Then in your [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) application:

```elixir
System.cmd("sudo", ["/usr/bin/service_to_run"], env: [{"FOO", "bar"}])
```

Comment: But be careful, this has obvious security consequences. For instance, many programs have escape to shell (they can be made to execute external commands) so allowing the user to run this program is equivalent to allowing it to run any program. In a corporate environment, talk with your CISO first.

Comment: how is the equivalent in windows 10 OS enviroment?

Comment: No idea, sorry for that.